# How to test element's width in cypress when the calculated width isn't accurate?

Tags: css, testing, cypress, e2e-testing, rounding-error

Let's say I have a `div` in the DOM with `'200px'` of width and a `class` of `'target'`.

In order to test its width with cypress, I should write the code below:

```js
cy.get('.target').should('have.css', 'width', '200px');
```

and there's a bunch of tests, testing widths and heights of elements...

...

Today something weird happened!

All these tests have failed because the value of `width` that cypress found was `200.0000000000032038879956012px` instead of `200px` !!!

The first solution that came into my mind was to test them on the actual numbers (ex, `200`), instead of the string (ex, `'200px'`) that the cypress found; which I think is an expensive idea!

**How do you think I can overcome this issue!?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can match without any conversion,

```js
cy.get('div')
  .invoke('css', 'width')
  .should('match', /200.*px/)   // matches 200.0000000000032038879956012px or 200px
```

Answer (score 3):

The test assertion `.should('have.css', ...)` is a wrapper for [Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) which reads the actual rendered value after all CSS has been applied.

It won't always correspond to the "input" setting applied in an inline style or via a style sheet, depending on other settings like justification, flex settings, media queries.

From a test perspective, you can switch to testing the "input" parameters,

- for inline styles
  `.should('have.attr', 'style', 'width: 200px')`
- for style sheets
  `.should('have.class', 'target')`

---

Alternatively use the `chai-almost` plugin to check close numeric values.

```js
const chaiAlmost = require('chai-almost');
chai.use(chaiAlmost(1))                           // 1 pixel variance

cy.get('.target')
  .invoke('css', 'width')                         // extract computed width 
  .then(widthStr => +widthStr.replace('px', ''))  // convert to number
  .should('almost.equal', 200);                   // approximate 200 +/- 1 px
```

Comment: Nice , But I'm looking for a more lightweight solution... Your solution has two extra works: "installing chaiAlmost" & "conversion"

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the 200px first into a number and then check that the number is in the range. Something like:

```js
cy.get('.target')
  .invoke('css', 'width')
  .then((width) => {
    expect(+width.replace('px', '')).to.be.within(200, 201)
  })
```

Comment: Looks better than [@Fody](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72415344/7421776)'s solution 